# Ignore row sorting MUI Datagrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, datagrid

how to ignore sorting "TOTAL" row in MUI library?

```
onSortModelChange={(test, neww) => {
    neww.api.state.sorting.sortedRows = [14881337, 2, 3]
    neww.api.setState({...neww.api.state})
}
}
```

view

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked awhile back, but just came across it. I believe you're looking for the `pinnedRows` prop. That way you can keep your `total row` at the bottom of the table.

```
  const rowsToPin = {
    bottom: [{ field: 'total', ...restOfRowToPin }}]
  };
    
  <DataGrid ...pinnedRows={rowsToPin} />
```

That will pin your total at the bottom, if you want it pinned at the top you just use `top`. You can pin multiple rows as well, hence the array.

Docs: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-pinning/

Answer (score 0):

Did you using DataGrid component?

Try this:

```
<DataGrid columns={[...columns, { field: 'total', sortable: false }]} />
```